# copy and save file on hard drive

Tags: r

Is there a way using R to copy and paste any given file at a given path to another `path/filename`? And without actually loading the file into the R-workspace? I haven't come across a way to do this on various R help sites.

Specifically I'm working with `DICOM` files that I want to `copy/paste/rename` en masse, but they can't, or rather shouldn't, be opened in R.

Before any one suggests using a dos-script or some other programming language, there is a reason why I want to do this in R. So, please, only those answer who can help with this issue in R.

Comment: sgibb, there's no need to be rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sgibb says, file.copy and file.rename are the functions you want; see...well, ?file.copy and ?file.rename. They do not require you to read the file into R, since they're basically a wrapper around the system file-copying utility.

Comment: Thanks for that Ironholds. I didn't find this in all my google searchs. Have now found the "File Manipulation" in the base package. So...the final hindrance for me moving completely to R for all my programming needs is now removed! Excellent...